# Angular2 Http Post not execute

Tags: typescript, angular

this is my method that I call from my service it not executed

```
addData(data) {
    let _body = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});

    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/obj/addData';
    let requestoptions:RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
         method: RequestMethod.Post,
         url: url,
         headers: headers,
         body : _body
    });
    console.log("test");
    return this._http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map((res:Response) => {
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        });
}
```

I added the console.log to verify that the method is called because although I call a method nothing done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `request` method doesn't get executed alone. Given you're already subscribing to the `addData` method, I'd suggest using the `post` method instead like this:

```
addData(data) {
    let _body = JSON.stringify(data);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'});

    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/obj/addData';

    console.log("test");

    return this._http.post(url, _body, { headers })
        .map((res:Response) => {
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In angular2 http requests aren't made until you subscribe to the http call. So if you add a subscribe to where you call the method on your service like so:

```
// In some component or service using your service
this.service.addData(data).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp));
```

Then you should see a request made and the response data posted in the console in this case.